# How to run Mono migration analyzer in windows XP?

Tags: mono

I have installed MONO2.10 in my Windows XP Desktop.Now, i have installed Mono Analyzer on my PC.While i am double clicking the MoMA.exe it raisig following Exception.Please Guide me to get out of this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are receiving this error message, you need to install the .NET framework from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=17153

Comment: thanks OVidiu... Its working good after installing .net framework 4.But, While i running MoMa.exe, i have put my exe file and necessary dll files and click next It shows the following error message... Can you briefly describe these errors? 1. Methods are still missing in Mono 2.Methods called marked with[MonoTodo]:1  we are using 3 party dll files for our Application like one is Ionic.zip.dll and second one is DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll.The Errors raised from these dll files.Please help me to get this...